# Remove custom Chart Js tool tip colour square

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have the following data for different months as bellow

```
var barChartData = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Task 1',
        backgroundColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        data: [50, 40, 23, 45, 67, 78, 23]
    }, {
        label: 'Task 2',
        backgroundColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
        data: [50, 40, 78, 23, 23, 45, 67]
    }, {
        label: 'Task 3',
        backgroundColor: "rgba(82,154,190,0.5)",
        data: [50, 67, 78, 23, 40, 23, 0]
    }]
};
```

I wanted to remove the colour square in front of the total label
[Expected Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiW7z.png)

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
var myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: barChartData,
    options: {
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: "Stacked Bar Chart"
        },
        tooltips: {
           intersect : false,
           mode: 'label',
            callbacks: {
                label: function(tooltipItem, data) {

                   var chartLabel = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label;
                   var valor = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];

                   var total = 0;
                   var label = '';                  

                   for (var i = 0; i < data.datasets.length; i++) {
                       total += data.datasets[i].data[tooltipItem.index];                       
                   }                     

                   if (tooltipItem.datasetIndex != data.datasets.length - 1) {
                      label += chartLabel + " : $" + valor.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,');                      
                   } else {
                        label += chartLabel + " : $" + valor.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,');
                      label = [label, " Total : $" + total];
                   }                   
                   return label;
                }
            }
        },
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                stacked: true,
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                stacked: true
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Here I am displaying the labels one after the other and finally calculating the Total of all three, but Total value generated with the last data set the colour, How we can remove the colour square in front of Total?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of including the total in the `tooltips.callbacks.label` function, use a `tooltips.callbacks.footer` function to return the total line.

Please have a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59968620/2358409) I gave to a similar question.